# CouchDB Fauxton "Save failed: undefined"

Tags: couchdb-2.0, fauxton

What could be causing this banner error 'Save failed: undefined' for v2.1.1 in Chrome 68 and Firefox 62 on Ubuntu?

With a fresh/recent login with admin permissions, suddenly (versus a few days ago with same system) I cannot create a new document in a custom database or the _users database, or edit any existing documents, or create a new database, but I can view all documents. Creating a database never gives the normal subsequent 'Database created successfully' banner.

[image: create custom doc screenshot]
[image: create user doc screenshot]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our server was out of storage space. Rule #1, save a backup **before** doing any remedying operation.